# POST 400 bad request React authentication

Tags: reactjs, axios

Any idea what may be causing that error? I am trying to authenticate the login with this API https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/warp/etn-device-checker-test/1.0#/default/post_login

```js
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const getIn = {
      "login":email,
      "password":password,
    };
          
    axios
      .post('https://js-test-api.etnetera.cz/api/v1/login', getIn)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);                 
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form >
        <label>email</label>
        <input value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="text"/>
        <label>password</label>
        <input type="text" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={onSubmit}>login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
        
export default Login
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be good for you if you console the input, because 400 bad request is related to input and out error (wrong input body).
And if you are able to console and value is printing correctly as json object, then please contact backend person if they are accepting as an object (JSON data in input.
try with this Sample:

```
axios.post('https://js-test-api.etnetera.cz/api/v1/login', getIn, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);

    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

output:[Error: Request failed with status code 401] (means it is able to send success request)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add headers to your post request.

```
axios.post(url, {
    //...data
}, {
    headers: {
       'content-type': 'application/json', 
   }
})
```

tried with postman and it worked.